# Icefaces 2.0: Problem with ice:selectInputDate inside custom component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces, composite-component

I am trying to create a custom JSF 2 component in order to avoid typing the converter and message tags for my date fields. I've done this with Icefaces 1.x using templates. With JSF 2, though, I was forced to use composite components; that is not going as well as I hoped.

The composite component has been successfully created:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="style" />
    <composite:attribute name="partialSubmit" />
    <composite:attribute name="rendered" />
    <composite:attribute name="immediate" />
    <composite:attribute name="value" required="true" />
    <composite:attribute name="pattern" required="true" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <ice:panelGroup rendered="#{cc.attrs.rendered}">
        <ice:selectInputDate value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
            style="#{cc.attrs.style}" id="input" renderAsPopup="true"
            partialSubmit="#{cc.attrs.partialSubmit }"
            immediate="#{cc.attrs.immediate }">
        </ice:selectInputDate>
        <ice:message for="input" style="color: red; display: block"></ice:message>
    </ice:panelGroup>
</composite:implementation>
```

When the property is null, the component behaves as expected. However, when I load data from my database, I get a java.sql.Date instance (despite the fact that my object uses java.util.date - the former extends the latter), I get this exception:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> Cannot convert 03/03/11 20:00 of type
> class java.util.Date to class
> java.sql.Date

What is weird is that if I use an `ice:selectInputDate` outside my composite component, I don't get that error. Any ideas?

Comment: Just curious: why were you forced to create composite components? Is this decision from higher levels or can't you use templates in IceFaces 2.0 anymore for some reason?

Comment: You can use templates. However, I had issues when I used my old templates with input components; I kept getting repeated component id exceptions. After wasting a day on trying to get it working, I decided to move on to the new approach. And there goes another day... :)

Comment: Just to make sure that I wasn't anywhere near classpath hell or something like that, I created a test project with IceFaces 2.0 in Tomcat 7. I created a bean with a java.util.date field and assigned an instance of java.sql.date to it. The problem **could** be reproduced. Looks like a bug...

Comment: When using a composite component instead of a normal component, right?

Comment: Right. In a nutshell, if your table has a date field and you map that into a java.util.Date field in your class and you try to access that field with an ice:selectInputDate inside a composite component, you're pretty much screwed.

Hibernate casts the java.sql.Date jdbc gives it into a java.util.Date, which is fine. When using composite components, jsf tries to coerce the selected date in the component (java.util.Date) into the type of the actual value of the back bean (in this chase, java.sql.Date). And that's what's going on. Ideas for a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, this might seem a little too extreme of a work around: rebuilding Tomcat. I figured tomcat doesn't change as often as JSF or ICEFaces. Call it a hack if you must; it solves my problem...

Download the tomcat source for the version you use and find a file named ELSupport.java. Look for the method with this signature:

```
public static final Object coerceToType(final Object obj,
        final Class<?> type) throws ELException {
```

Now add the following lines to it, right above the line that throws the ELException:

```
if (java.util.Date.class.isAssignableFrom(obj.getClass())){
    return obj;
}
```

It pretty much just prevents the exception from being thrown when the object is an instance of a sub-class from java.util.Date.

Does anyone think this is a contribution to the Tomcat project? I never really contributed with anything open source, so I don't really know how it works.